# How to send email with C# on Windows Phone 8 with from field

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

As I tried to explain in the title, I need to send emails in my WP8 app from my own account not by the existing accounts on the phone. I plan to use this for password reset process. What I currently use is:

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

```
        EmailComposeTask emailcomposer = new EmailComposeTask();
        emailcomposer.To = "AMailAdress";
        emailcomposer.Subject = "subject from test app";
        emailcomposer.Body = "This is a test mail from Email Composer";
        emailcomposer.Show();
```

}

This just sends via user's accounts. Shortly, I need a way to set from field sending an email. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should better send email from the server, not from windows phone app.
If it doesn't need user's account then there is no reason for the email to be created from the phone.

Maybe you can POST to an URL with required info, and make the server (your service) send the email.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to try this but I use Windows Azure Moblie Services (which I am new to) for the app. Do you have further information about creating and sending emails with Azure?

Comment: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/11/12/Sending-e-mail-from-Windows-Azure.aspx - You'll still need a SMTP server to send the email though

Comment: If his worked for you please mark the answer as accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer